# VBA Macros in Outlook 2010 are suddenly disabled despite trust center settings and digital signatures?

Tags: vba, outlook

*Please read all points below before attempting to answer the question*

I'm at the end of my wits and the macros should run based on my settings.

1. My Trust Center Setting is "Notifications for all signed macros, all other macros disabled." I am unable to change these settings because centralized IT sets them.
2. I stuck it to centralized IT, signed my own macros and added myself to Trusted Publishers. The macros worked well for several weeks.
3. Yesterday afternoon, my macros suddenly stopped working. My trust center remains the same and the Trusted Publishers list remains the same - the publisher of my certificate still appears there.
4. I double checked the macros were signed - removed all my code and just tried a MsgBox that said "Test" - even that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by signing the project with a new certificate.

Strangely, the first time I tried this it did not work. I either missed the message indicating that it was a new certificate and to trust the publisher or it was a weird glitch.

Either way I am back to writing and running macros with glee!